# How correctly to use the snippet() function?

Tags: sphinx

My first Sphinx app almost works!
I successfully save path,title,content as attributes in index!

But I decided go to SphinxQL PDO from AP:
I found snippets() example [thanks to barryhunter again](http://www.nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example5-sphinxql.phps) but don't see how use it.

This is my working code, except snippets():

```
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=ununtu;port=9306;charset=utf8', '', '');
  if(isset($_GET['query']) and strlen($_GET['query']) > 1)
  {
        $query = $_GET['query'];
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM `test1` WHERE MATCH('$query')";
        foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $info) {

                //snippet. don't works
                $docs = array();

                foreach () {
                    $docs[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($info['content']))."'";
                }

                $result = mysql_query("CALL SNIPPETS((".implode(',',$docs)."),'test1','" . mysql_real_escape_string($query) . "')",$conn);
                $reply = array();

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    $reply[] = $row['snippet'];
                }



                // path, title out. works
                $path = rawurlencode($info["path"]); $title = $info["title"];
                $output =  '<a href=' . $path . '>' . $title . '</a>'; $output = str_replace('%2F', '/', $output);
                print( $output . "<br><br>");
        }
}
```

I have got such structure from Sphinx index:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 244
            [path] => DOC7000/zdorovie1.doc
            [title] => zdorovie1.doc
            [content] => Stuff content
```

I little bit confused with array of docs.
Also I don't see advice: "So its should be MUCH more efficient, to compile the documents and call buildExcepts just once. 
But even more interesting, is as you sourcing the the text from a sphinx attribute, can use the SNIPPETS() sphinx function (in setSelect()!) in the main query. SO you dont have to receive the full text, just to send back to sphinx. ie sphinx will fetch the text from attribute internally. even more efficient!
"
Tell me please how I should change code for calling snippet() once for docs array, but output path (link), title for every doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well because your data comes from sphinx, you can just use the `SNIPPET()` function (not `CALL SNIPPETS()`!)

```
$query = $conn->quote($_GET['query']);
$sql= "SELECT *,SNIPPET(content,$query) AS `snippet` FROM `test1` WHERE MATCH($query)";
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $info) {
    $path = rawurlencode($info["path"]); $title = $info["title"];
    $output =  '<a href=' . $path . '>' . $title . '</a>'; $output = str_replace('%2F', '/', $output);
    print("$output<br>{$info['snippet']}<br><br>");
}
```

the highlighted text is right there in the main query, dont need to mess around with bundling the data back up to send to sphinx.

Also shows you should be escaping the raw query from user.

(the example you found does that, because the full text comes fom MySQL - not sphinx - so it has no option but to mess around sending data back and forth!)

Just for completeness, if REALLY want to use `CALL SNIPPETS()` would be something like

```
<?php

$query =$conn->quote($_GET['query']);

//make query request
$sql= "SELECT * FROM `test1` WHERE MATCH($query)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//build list of docs to send
$docs = array();
foreach ($rows as $info) {
    $docs[] = $conn->quote(strip_tags($info['content']));
}

//make snippet reqest
$sql = "CALL SNIPPETS((".implode(',',$docs)."),'test1',$query)";

//decode reply
$reply = array();
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    $reply[] = $row['snippet'];
}

//output results using $rows, and cross referencing with $reply
foreach ($rows as $idx => $info) {

    // path, title out. works
    $path = rawurlencode($info["path"]); $title = $info["title"];
    $output =  '<a href=' . $path . '>' . $title . '</a>'; $output = str_replace('%2F', '/', $output);
    $snippet = $reply[$idx];

    print("$output<br>$snippet<br><br>");
}
```

Shows putting the rows into an array, because need to lopp though the data TWICE. Once to 'bundle' up the docs array to send. Then again to acully display rules, when have $rows AND $reply both available.

Comment: it's works now! Only I spent an hour try to research mysqli till didn't found that it no need in PDO:    $query = "'".$_GET['query']."'";
        //$query = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query'])."'";

Comment: by the way,  I need replace '%2F' only once, not twice:   str_replace('%2F', '/', ... why it born once?

Comment: Umm, you *still* need escaping with pdo. It doesnt 'magically' escape if you manually contstrict the SQL as a string. Although with PDO can do prepared queries, which then dont need escaping. None of these examples are using prepared queries.

Comment: PDO has a dedicated function http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php - use that instead of mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use PDO syntax completely, rather than mixing in mysql_* functions.

Comment: BTW I checked quote() escaping just now (if I correctly understand it). That line ( $query = $conn->quote($_GET['query']);
  ) allowed '`!@#$%^&*\<>' but no '/' : " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ". But anyway it is not very dangerous for my app which will work without internet access in corporative environment.

Comment: I mean when I type the symbols '`!@#$%^&*\<>' after search phrase - it works fine (escaped input?), but when I type '/' then I have got a warning.